# Not entering if/else block

Tags: c#

I have the following code. When I type `0` into the console, I expect the console to display "Please re-enter your age" but that `if` block is never entered and the program exits. What am I doing wrong?

```
Console.WriteLine("Please entre your first name:");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your last name:");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please type your age:");
            Console.ReadLine();

            int minAge = 18;
            int maxAge = 68;

            if (minAge < 18)
               if (maxAge > 68)

                Console.WriteLine("Please re-enter your age");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Please choose f for female or m for male:");
```

Comment: You've hard coded the minAge and maxAge and are not using the console input *at all*. Please put your if/else blocks into curly braces unless you enjoy bug hunting.

Comment: You aren't actually processing the age (or first and last names) in any way. `minAge < 18` is always `false` and the top-level `if` condition has no else branch. You should consider putting braces around your `if` conditions to make them clearer.

Comment: Thank you, @Stephen Kennedy and @Lee! I'm working on this now, and more issues appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following may be it helps,

```
        int userage;
        Console.WriteLine("Please type your age:");
        userage=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int minAge = 18;
        int maxAge = 68;

        if (userage>minAge || userage<maxAge)
                Console.WriteLine("Age is not accepted");
            else
            Console.WriteLine("Your Age is {0}",userage.ToString());
            //do what ever you want
            //Console.WriteLine("Please choose f for female or m for male:");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not reading the user input into an `age` variable. When you do, you need to take account of the user possibly typing non-numeric characters. You're also not wrapping your `if`/`else` blocks inside curly braces which is resulting in the logical flow not matching your intentions.

The following code reads the console input into an age variable, rejecting unparseable input by using [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx), and it retains your `minAge` and `maxAge` values as [constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx). We keep [looping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/370s1zax.aspx) until the user has input a valid number as an age, and exit if they are ineligible to continue because they are too young or too old:

```
const int minAge = 18;
const int maxAge = 68;
int age;

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please type your age:");
} while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age));

if (age < minAge || age > maxAge)
{
    Console.WriteLine("I'm sorry, this application is for people aged {0} to {1} only", minAge, maxAge);
    return; // or exit console app
}

Console.WriteLine("Please choose f for female or m for male:");
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not storing inputted age. Because of that the program never reach the next part, since you're comparing minAge with minAge and maxAge with maxAge. Maybe you can use

```
int age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Readline())
```

edit : if you don't want any exception, you can handle it by using

```
int age;
bool res = Int32.TryParse(Console.Readline(), out age);
if (!res)
     Console.WriteLine("Please re-enter your age");
```

then use them in the next part

```
 if (age < minAge || age > maxAge )
      Console.WriteLine("Please re-enter your age");
 else
      Console.WriteLine("Please choose f for female or m for male:");
```

Comment: This answer is nearly there but it will fail with a `System.FormatException` if the user types something like "Hi!" when asked for their age.

Comment: @Stephen : You're right, thank you. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: But when entering a correct age, the console says "press any key to..." it doesn't writes " please choose f for female..."